# Check for connection loop if drops restart second loop

Tags: bash

I have bash script which is looping and fetching info from online, I ran test overnight yesterday and everything went smootly until my connection dropped for 2 mins and script got stuck.

So to overcome this I need your help consctruction loop which is checking for connection if it fails restart bash script again.

Example of script which I am using right now:

```
while true; do 
        xargs -d '\n' -I LINE -P2 go run main.go -d LINE -o file < domain && 
        xargs -d '\n' -I LINE -P3 ./script -d LINE < domain && 
        xargs -d '\n' -I LINE -P2 python3 script4.py -d LINE --output file < domain && 
        xargs -d '\n' -I LINE -P2 python3 script3.py -u LINE -o file.txt < domain && 
        xargs -d '\n' -I LINE -P3 script2 -t LINE -o recon < domain && 
        xargs -d '\n' -I LINE python3 script.py -t 020f3fe83162e016114b32ad9542 -d LINE < domain && 
    mv *.txt savehere && dos2unix savehere/*.txt && sort savehere/*.txt | uniq | tr -d '<>,' > results-$(date +%d-%m-%Y_%H_%p).txt 
done
```

Comment: See https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic

Comment: exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize curl for example if your connection is http / https based.

Something like this in your loop:

```
curl http://domain.example.com || $(echo "I am unable to connect to http://domain.example.com and will sleep for 60 seconds; sleep 60;continue)
```

it will try to fetch http content from http://domain.example.com and if it fails - it will echo text and sleep for 60 seconds; then restart the while from the top so it's best to add it to the top of the while loop :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! however this only checks at the start of the loop, if my connection falls in middle of bash script then its game over for me, because all executed scripts do use internet connection.

Comment: You can either run curl after each command in the loop or call a function that evaluates via curl if the connection is alive. All of your commands have return codes that indicate if the command exited with success (return code == 0) or not (return code <> 0).Return code is stored in $? variable in bash and can be used to exit /restart program or handle errors.